# SQL Server stored procedure line number issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, deadlock

I am using SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. I met with issue which says line 9 of stored procedure foo is meeting with dead lock issue. My question is how to find exactly the 9th line of the stored procedure?

My confusion is because of coding format issue, how to locate 9th line correctly.

thanks in advance,
George

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the 9th line from the CREATE PROCEDURE statement. A SQL statement is often multiline so "line 9" will refer to the first line of the statement (eg INSERT or UPDATE)

However, if you have comments above the CREATE PROCEDURE or blank lines before it then you can't rely on this... so run ALTER PROC with ALTER PROC as first line in the batch.

Comment: 1. So, the most reliable way is to use alter proc from SQL Server Management Studio, then count the line number? 2. Shall I remove any comments above the store procedure from alter proc code generated by SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: My confusion is about whether lines above alter procedure will be counted as line number count -- "SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO", and also how to treat multi-line statement in store procedure to deal with line number count?

Comment: It's line XX from the CREATE PROC

Comment: Including such lines "SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO"? I think such line are created by SQL Server automatically, not created by the developed who writes store procedure?

Comment: Line 1 = "CREATE PROC". Ignore the SET statements

Comment: You mean the create proc scripts generated from SSMS --> select a store procedure --> Create Store Procedure?

Comment: Why you prefer to use create then alter?

Comment: And how will the line be counted if there is long statement which will span for multiple lines in SSMS query editor?

Comment: CREATE or ALTER does not matter. It depends if you script for create or to modify. As long as CREATE or ALTER if first.

Comment: I have tried another option, which will us Go to Management Studio>> Tools >> Options >>, then in tree view open Text Editor >> All Language >> line number option, and I think this option will falsely treat line number, since long statement which crosses multiple lines will be treated as multiple lines. Am I correct? Any comments?

Comment: No idea, but it's he script/edit line numbers not the line numbers parsed at execution time.

Comment: i dont understand this... error line number is often 50+ lines higher than # of lines in my CREATE STORED script.. counting all the comments etc

Answer (score 14):

A tip I learnt from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565614/how-can-i-get-the-actual-stored-procedure-line-number-from-an-error-message/4566344#4566344) ...

If you do

```
sp_helptext procedure_name
```

SQL will output its 'remembered' version of the create procedure statement, and that is what it gets it line numbers from apparently. If you have SSMS in 'grid output' mode then it will also output the line numbers (as the row numbers of the result set).

NB: in my case it was working from the CREATE PROCEDURE statement plus a bunch of comments above it, so line 1 was about 6 lines above the CREATE PROCEDURE call.

Comment: Just as an FYI in my case it was `sp_helptext proc_name` with no parens. The parens may have been in the example for some other purpose, but it didn't work for me until I took them out. +1 though!

Answer (score 4):

The line numbers outputted by `sp_helptext` are totally different than the line number you see in the error message.

For instance, in my stored procedure error it said the error occured on line number 194 but actually my stored procedure showed only 136 lines when I showed `sp_helptext`. BTW, I used SQL Server 2008.

Comment: i think your best to re-run your SP using the alter script and make sure alter procedure is the first line and no comments etc above. then the presented error line numbers should match.