# TRY..CATCH Error_Line()....line

Tags: t-sql, error-handling

I'm looking at this example provided by MS as I'm trying to learn `Try...Catch`. I understand the syntax and Output (for the most part) but I have one question:

The Output will show the Error_Line as '4'. This is fine but if I remove the line break between `GO` and `BEGIN TRY` it'll show the Error_Line as '3'. I just want to understand the logic here.

What I imagine is happening is that SQL Server is counting the lines by beginning the batch immediately after `GO`, even if that line is blank but I do not know this for certain. Can anyone clarify? If that theory is correct, wouldn't that make finding errors difficult if scripts are written with line breaks like this?

```
-- Verify that the stored procedure does not already exist.  
IF OBJECT_ID ( 'usp_GetErrorInfo', 'P' ) IS NOT NULL   
    DROP PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo;  
GO  

-- Create procedure to retrieve error information.  
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_GetErrorInfo  
AS  
SELECT  
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
    ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
GO  
                                        --Line 1
BEGIN TRY                               --Line 2
    -- Generate divide-by-zero error.   --Line 3
    SELECT 1/0;                         --Line 4
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    -- Execute error retrieval routine.  
    EXECUTE usp_GetErrorInfo;  
END CATCH;
```

Comment: that error line isn't always going to be the exact line. It may just be the start of the statement. if the statement spans multiple lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get the actual stored procedure line number from an error message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565614/how-can-i-get-the-actual-stored-procedure-line-number-from-an-error-message)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really rely on `ERROR_LINE()`, especially when the error is thrown in internal stored procedure or there is dynamic T-SQL statement which is executed.

But do you really need the exact error line?

1. in real production code, the fix for the line causing the error may not be so obvious as in your example;
2. it will be better to debug the stored procedure or the function with the corresponding input parameter in order to reproduce the error

In this way it will be easier to fix an issue. In order to debug a SQL routine:

1. just script it
2. remove the `drop` and `create` stuff
3. add declare in front of the input parameters and initialized them with the values causing the error

Basically, instead of the exact error line (which can be easily fine having the correct input parameters and executing the routine) you may found useful two things:

- which routing is causing the error (for example, you can add additional parameter to user `usp_GetErrorInfo` SP which is yielding the SP name as well
- the input parameters which are causing the error (this can be done using separated table for logging the errors in the `CATCH` clause - you simple insert the input parameters in the table and information about the error)

Having this information, it will be easy to reproduce and then fix an issue (in many cases).