# msg 8152 level 16 state 2 string or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I am getting this error while executing a procedure

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 2, Procedure SP_xxxxx, Line 92 String or
>   binary data would be truncated.

I have created a temp table which I will load the data from main table once in procedure and I would be using this table not the main table as main table has huge volume of data and many unnecessary columns.

When I run the below code from sql server management studio then there is no error but when I run this code from a procedure then their is the above error message.

```
Insert into abc_TMP // tmp for procedure with required columns
Select 
    Item,
    Description,
    size,
    qty,
    stock,
    Time ,
    Measure

    from abc   // main table has many columns
```

Comment: I suspect some of the datatypes and lengths in `abc_TMP` and `abc` do not match exactly. Post the DDL for those two tables

Comment: @Mazhar actually I have created same DDL for both tables, and If I run as a statement then works perfectly, problem is only when I run from procedure

Comment: Does the procedure contain anything other than what you've posted?

Comment: @Mazhar yes their is approx 600 lines of code but error is pointing to this part of the procedure which is 92 line

Comment: And you've confirmed that by executing the proc by commentting out that piece of code? Sometimes the line number can be red-herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that you are [looking at the wrong line of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4565614/how-can-i-get-the-actual-stored-procedure-line-number-from-an-error-message) in the stored proc.

When you open the proc, i.e. `ALTER...` you have a header on the stored proc that will throw the line number out.

If you run this, replacing `proc_name` with your procedure name:

```
sp_helptext proc_name
```

That will give you the code that the procedure will actually run, with accurate line numbers if you paste it into a new window.

Then you'll see where the actual error is happening.

If you want a simple way to prove this theory, put a bunch of `Print 'some sql 1'`, `Print 'some sql 2'` lines in around the code you think is causing the error and see what is output when the error is thrown.

Comment: Its an excellent catch @Tanner.. now when I run SP_Helptext line number pointing to different line of code..

Comment: I was able to solve the issue with your help.. thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

One way to check this issue, is to see length of each value

Assume you have table like below

```
create table t
(
col1 varchar(10),
col2 varchar(10)
)
```

Inserts into the table will fail,if  you try to insert more than 10 characters,if you try to insert them in a batch, you will not get offending value.

So you need to check its length like below , prior to insert

```
;with cte
as
(
select 
len(col1) as col1,
len(Col2) as col2
from table
)
select * from cte where col2>10
```

There has been number of requests raised with Microsoft to enhance error message  and they have finally fixed this issue in SQL2019.

Now you can get the exact value causing the issue

[image]

References:
https://voiceofthedba.com/2018/09/26/no-more-mysterious-truncation/

Comment: Thanks sir.. I will try and let you know in 5 min

Comment: But, why  I am not getting this error when I execute the same code in a query window and not by using procedure

Comment: You should get same error  in both places,if data is same

Comment: data is same but error only when run through procedure

Comment: think he's looking at the wrong line, see my answer